# Парсер страницы

Tags: c#, парсер

когда пытаюсь вывести значения в CheckedListBox значения, на переменную node2 выскакивает ошибка System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
Не могу понять как исправить.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("https://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport?rname=ivr_report_zone&rdate=20180401");

        HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"aid_files_list\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a");

        foreach (var item in nodes2)
            {
                table.Add(new ReportData() { url = item.Attributes["href"].Value, name = item.InnerHtml });
            }

        table.All(p => { checkedListBox1.Items.Add(p.name); return true; });
    }
```

Comment: Падает на строке `table.All(p => { checkedListBox1.Items.Add(p.name); return true; });` ?

Comment: adrug, в самом начале цикла  foreach (var item in nodes2)

Comment: что вот эта конструкция вам возвращает?
 `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"aid_files_list\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")`

Comment: `SelectNodes` вернул вам не пустой массив, а null.
Так реализована библиотека. Почитайте описание метода. Вам нужна проверка на null.

Comment: tym32167, http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes я взяла отсюда пример, получаю просто элемент xpath

Comment: или добавить это `?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>()`, но вроде нужно будет еще типы привести к общему

Comment: А можно код в студию, пожалуйста? Чего-то перестала понимать что происходит после справки майкрософт

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно метод load возвращает пустой документ. Скорее всего нужно дополнительная настройка для HtmlWeb, возможно куки.

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(website);
String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Куки тут не нужны, отчет лежит в открытом доступе, его может скачать любой желающий.

Comment: Попробуйте установить контейнер как в ответе

Comment: Только что нашел что htmlweb не поддерживает https

Comment: Используйте HttpClient для получения содержимого

Comment: Можно пример с HttpClient?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158912(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: честно скажу, мне мало чего  понятно, простите

Comment: При помощи этого метода вы получаете html, а затем используете его для парсинга в htmlagilitypack, код в ответе

Answer (score 0):

`SelectNodes` не нашел ни одну node  с вашим xpath'ом и вернул вам не пустой массив, а null. В описаниях метода написано это. Вам нужна проверка на null.

```
 HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"aid_files_list\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a");

if (nodes2 == null) return;
```

Comment: Я ее, конечно,  сделала. Но как мне вывести данные со страницы? Он возвращает пустое значение. Я хочу вывести ( для начала) один отчет в checkedlistbox и потом другое делать с ним.

Comment: Если данные, которые вам нужны действительно там есть, то у вас не правильный xpath

Comment: Давайте проверим? https://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport?rname=ivr_report_zone&rdate=20180401 //*[@id="aid_files_list"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a

Comment: @Owl_Livi откройте верстку ctrl+u  и поймете что там нет тега tbody. То что вы его видите через инспектор значит лишь, что страница достраивается после загрузки скриптами.

Comment: подскажите, как правильно извлечь xpath? Чтобы не наступать на те же грабли

Comment: @Owl_Livi методом проб и ошибок.
Изучите типичные примеры в гайдах от других людей.

Comment: Эээээээ, что-то у меня тоже это не особо получается. Я получала xpath вот  так https://pp.userapi.com/c830709/v830709902/fe7d3/oaCe1b_D4NQ.jpg

Comment: @Owl_Livi повторяю. Почитайте как работает xpath  и напишите его самостоятельно.

Comment: Adrug, Спасибо,читала. 2 программы работают с использованием xpath, эта не хочет, в общем и написала сюда за помощью. С данным, максимум получилось так "//*[@id=\"aid_files_list\"]/div//a[1]", но опять же не работает. Поэтому, прошу помочь с xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Вам правильно говорят, что надо видеть какой исходный код страницы возвращается, потому что идти по DOM - это не всегда правильное решение. В одном случае оно работает, а в другом нет.
Попробуйте такой xpath:

```
//a[contains(@title, 'Опубликовано')]
```

или можете так, если хотите сразу получить ссылку

```
//a[contains(@title, 'Опубликовано')]/@href
```